# Double inequalities in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, math

Is it possible to write double inequalities in an **if-statement?**

ex: `if (x <= y <= z) do stuff;`

Comment: Well, you can write them, they just don't mean what you probably expect. Your example would be parsed as `if ((x <= y) <= z) do stuff;`, and depending on whether `x <= y` would evaluate to `if (1 <= z)` or `if (0 <= z)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope - Objective-C is a superset of the C language, and uses the same syntax as C for `if` statements. You'll have to split that up into two inequalities: `if (x <= y && y <= z)`.